# How can I inject the JS Chunks at the <body> tag instead of <head> using Vite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I am building a reactjs app and when I try to run `npm run build`, the js chunks are being injected at the `<head>` tags instead of the `<body>` tags. I have tried adding the following code to my `vite.config.js` file but it still doesn't work

```
export default {
 optimizeDeps: {
inject: 'body'
},
```

Kindly help. Thank you

Comment: I've edited to the correct name

Comment: This looks like what you want ~ https://github.com/baieceo/vite-plugin-entry-inject